# Can you display a success message after redirect without using a session?

Tags: php

Is it possible to show success message on another page without using `$_SESSION`?

Example

process.php

```
header('location:/thank-you.php');
$success = 'Thank you. Please come again';
exit();
```

thank-you.php

`if(isset($success)) { echo $success; }`

Currently it's not working. Let me know how it can be done.

Comment: it is possible but ugly. And there is nothing bad or complicated in using sessions

Comment: You could potentially use cookies, but using $_SESSION would be cleaner.

Comment: Add some incomprehensible query argument? `http://example.com/thank-you.php?p=np` and check for that query var in the thank-you script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

process.php

```
header('location: /thank-you.php?mess=1');
exit();
```

thank-you.php

```
$mess = isset($_REQUEST['mess']) ? $_REQUEST['mess'] : null;
if($mess == 1) {
  echo 'Thank you. Please come again'; }
```

This is not optimal but should work for simple scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

`header('location:/thank-you.php?success=Thank+You+Please+Come+again');`

and

```
$success =$_GET['success'];
if(isset($success)) { echo $success; }
```

Comment: Query string is a good suggestion but want to mention `strip_tags` to avoid XSS: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Directly outputting a variable passed in the query string is not a very good idea. Be careful of page injection issues (xss).